# Error inflating class <unknown>

Tags: android, textview, android-inflate, xml-drawable

I am trying to work my way in UI. I am trying to set stateListDrawable for list entries. All I am trying to do is change the color of the list item's layout when the item is pressed, and while the list item is pressed I want to change the color of the text as well.

I am getting the following error stack:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(  360): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(  360): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class <unknown>
E/AndroidRuntime(  360):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
E/AndroidRuntime(  360):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
E/AndroidRuntime(  360):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
E/AndroidRuntime(  360):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
E/AndroidRuntime(  360):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
E/AndroidRuntime(  360):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
E/AndroidRuntime(  360):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
```

The XML that is inflated is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/help_list_container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dip"
    android:background="@drawable/default_list_selection">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/help_list_text" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="@drawable/help_text_color">
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I can get the program to work if I remove the `android:textColor` property from the xml. Is there a way I can use a stateListDrawable to control the texColor of a listitem from the xml?

The stateListDrawable works for `android:background` in LinearLayout, but it won't for the textColor property of TextView. The state list xml is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/white"
              android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/black" />
</selector>
```

Any response would be appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I was wrongly using a drawable to change the textColor of a TextView. Instead, I should have used a ColorStateList

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/white" />
   <item android:color="@color/black"/>
 </selector>
```